# Ruby Always Round Up

Tags: ruby

I feel like a crazy person. I'd like to round all fractions up to the nearest whole number.

For example, 67/30 = 2.233333333334. I would like to round that up to 3. If the result is not a whole number, I never want to round down, only up.

This is what I'm trying:

```
puts 67/30.to_f.ceil
```

Here are examples of what I'm looking for:

- 67/30 = 3
- 50/100 = 1
- 2/2 = 1

Any ideas? Thanks much!

Comment: Best not to have unnecessary tags (here Rails). It's a time-waster for those only interested in Rails questions, those who filter out Rails questions would miss a question that might be of interest to them.

Comment: Another way: `(67+30-1)/30 => 3`

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The problem is that you're currently calling `ceil` on `30.to_f`. Here's how Ruby evaluates it:

```
(67)/(30.to_f.ceil)
# .ceil turns the float into an integer again
(67)/(30.0.ceil)
# and now it's just an integer division, which will be 2
67/30 # = 2
```

To solve this, you can just add parenthesis:

```
puts (67/30.to_f).ceil  # = 3
```

Comment: does that mean .ceil method converts `30.0` to `30` in `67/30.0.ceil` instead of performing an actual ceil?

Comment: @Rahul It means, the original expression is actually evaluated as `(67)/(30.to_f.ceil)` which defeats the whole idea.

Comment: fivedigit, I see you're closing in on four of 'em.

Comment: @Holger Just, I improved the answer according to your notation with parenthesis, thanks!

Comment: @Cary Swoveland, Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I was referring to your name and rep. It was late.